# Post datepicker value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

I have two date picker (one for start date, and one for end date):

I have two pages (the page where the datepicker is found with its script, and the php page where the post is).

Below is what happens in the main page:

```
<script>
$(function() {

     $(".dpicks").datepicker();

    $('.dpicks').on('change', function() {
        $val = $(this).val();
                        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";

    var datastring = $('#testform').serialize(); // this will create key/value pairs to send to the phph page like `duration5=5` with a `&` separating each key/value pair 
$('#display-datastring').html(datastring); // this line is just so you can see the variable being created 
$.ajax({ 
url: 'fetch_pages.php', 
type: 'post', 
data: datastring, 
success: function(res){ 

$('#results').html(res); 
} 
}); 
    });
      $(".dpicke").datepicker();

    $('.dpicke').on('change', function() {
        $val = $(this).val();
                        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";

    var datastring = $('#testform').serialize(); // this will create key/value pairs to send to the phph page like `duration5=5` with a `&` separating each key/value pair 
$('#display-datastring').html(datastring); // this line is just so you can see the variable being created 
$.ajax({ 
url: 'fetch_pages.php', 
type: 'post', 
data: datastring, 
success: function(res){ 

$('#results').html(res); 
} 
}); 
    });
  });

</script>
```

the input

```
            <input type="text"  placeholder="Start" style="width: 40%;" name="dateStart"  class="dpicks" > 
                            <label id="Paylbl0">To</label>

             <input type="text"  style="width: 40%;" placeholder="End" name="dateEnd" class="dpicke">
```

on the fetch_pages.php

```
$startDate = isset($_POST['startDate']) ? $_POST['startDate']: null; 
$endDate = isset($_POST['endDate']) ? $_POST['endDate']: null;
```

Now what's happening succesfully is that when the datepicker does work, where when i select the input the datepicker appears and a date is displayed but i don't think the post is executed because i echo out startDate and endDate nothing is displayed

Comment: Well, `dateStart` isn't the same as `startDate`, and `dateEnd` isn't the same as `endDate`. Use the correct values that matches the names of the elements, and you'd be getting closer.

Comment: If possible provide a fiddle, I have a suspicion that the when the datepicker initializes something in your inputs becomes invalid, if an input has invalid fields it can result in a empty submit for the field

Comment: sorry you guys were right, i named it incorectly, now my minor issue relies here the date format, right now it outputs as 03/18/2015 but i need to output as yyyy-mm-dd